# C++ regex search specific chinese pattern

Tags: c++, regex, wstring

I need to regex search specific chinese pattern from C++ string
For example I have a source string "什么手机好" and a pattern "什么(.*)好"

I use boost::regex_search and wstring to do this , but there is something wrong
when the search string has english or number, the code doesn't work, for example , source string is "abc什么efg手机好" pattern is "什么(.*)好", the code do ACT2. And  source string is "" (empty string) pattern is "什么(.*)好" , the code do ACT1

I want to know how to fix it.

func

```
std::wstring string2wstring(const std::string& s) {
     setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");
     int iWLen = std::mbstowcs(NULL, s.c_str(), s.length());
     wchar_t *lpwsz= new wchar_t[iWLen + 1];
     std::mbstowcs(lpwsz, s.c_str(), s.length());
     std::wstring wstrResult(lpwsz);
     delete []lpwsz;
     return wstrResult;
}

std::wstring ws = string2wstring(s);
boost::wregex wpattern(string2wstring(pattern));
if (boost::regex_search(ws, wpattern) == true) {
   do ACT1;
} else {
   do ACT2;
}
```

Comment: compile is ok, error from unittest.

Answer (score 0):

It is embarrassed that I needn't use wstring to deal chinese regex.

Just making query and pattern gbk-string can fix it.

```
boost::regex_search(query,pattern)
```